# create object within object Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

My Code :

```
for( var i in zones) {
                    var latlons1 = new google.maps.LatLng(zones[i].b.cen_x, zones[i].b.cen_y);
                    var latlons2 = new google.maps.LatLng(zones[i].b.max_x, zones[i].b.max_y);
                    var latlons3 = new google.maps.LatLng(zones[i].b.min_x, zones[i].b.min_y);

                     obj1 = { zones[i].n = {1:latlons1,2:latlons2,3:latlons3}  } //here object creation

                    console.log(obj1);

                }
```

what i am doing wrong? consol log error shows at object create.

Comment: you're not properly using objects on that `obj1` line.

Comment: thanks for answer, please show me how to use object at this moment Properly

Comment: If you are using numbers as index, why are you not using an array to start?

Comment: @Dest this is nothing close to a tutorial website.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating an object literal in JavaScript the key and value are separated by a colon (`:`). Also note that if you want to use dynamic keys then you'll need to use the square bracket notation for setting and accessing those properties. So this:

```
obj1 = { zones[i].n = {1:latlons1,2:latlons2,3:latlons3}  }
```

should become:

```
obj1 = {};
obj1[zones[i].n] = {
    1: latlons1,
    2: latlons2,
    3: latlons3
};
```

If you're confused as to why you have to do it this way it's because the keys aren't evaluated. While you meant that the key should be the value that's referenced by `zones[i].n`, JavaScript interprets it as the key should be the string literal `"zones[i].n"`, which obviously isn't what you want.

Comment: Yes, in that case `zones[i].n` will be the top level key which contains an object with three props.

Answer (score 0):

To use an object within an object,

```
    //An object within an object
    var NestedObject=new Object();
    NestedObject.one={
    sad:{
    d:"Add"
    }
    }
```

I solved this using experimental coding within Codecademy.com;
Thanks for letting me share my answer!